# Unreal Engine 5 Assertion failed on project startup

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal

After restarting my computer UE 5 is no longer able to load my project, it gets stuck at 86%. after crashing I receive this crash log

```
Assertion failed: Object->HasAnyFlags( RF_BeginDestroyed ) && !Object->HasAnyFlags( RF_FinishDestroyed ) [File:D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\UObject\GarbageCollection.cpp] [Line: 4051]

UnrealEditor_CoreUObject
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject
UnrealEditor_CoreUObject
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
kernel32
ntdll
```

I'm not sure what could have caused this as I didn't make any changes between launches

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately, your crash stack is missing a lot of information.   That said, searching around, this might help you.  https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/why-is-my-plugin-failing-to-open/1373946

Comment: Thank you deleting the binaries, saved and intermediate folders out of the project file worked for me